# App; had used a different AppComponent; during pre-verification

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso, dagger-2

I am having problems running my espresso-tests on one device - I am getting the following error:

```
W/dalvikvm(10180): Class resolved by unexpected DEX: Lorg/ligi/passandroid/App;(0x43876120):0x660f9000 ref [Lorg/ligi/passandroid/AppComponent;] Lorg/ligi/passandroid/AppComponent;(0x43876120):0x64e2f000
W/dalvikvm(10180): (Lorg/ligi/passandroid/App; had used a different Lorg/ligi/passandroid/AppComponent; during pre-verification)
D/AndroidRuntime(10180): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(10180): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x433101a0)
E/MonitoringInstrumentation(10180): Exception encountered by: Thread[main,5,main]. Dumping thread state to outputs and pining for the fjords.
E/MonitoringInstrumentation(10180): java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation
E/MonitoringInstrumentation(10180):     at org.ligi.passandroid.App.onCreate(App.java:26)
E/MonitoringInstrumentation(10180):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1013)
E/MonitoringInstrumentation(10180):     at android.support.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:323)
E/MonitoringInstrumentation(10180):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4749)
E/MonitoringInstrumentation(10180):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:172)
E/MonitoringInstrumentation(10180):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1368)
E/MonitoringInstrumentation(10180):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/MonitoringInstrumentation(10180):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
E/MonitoringInstrumentation(10180):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
E/MonitoringInstrumentation(10180):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/MonitoringInstrumentation(10180):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/MonitoringInstrumentation(10180):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
E/MonitoringInstrumentation(10180):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
E/MonitoringInstrumentation(10180):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I excluded everything so there should be no duplicate libs - here my dependencies for the test-app:

```
_withMapsWithAnalyticsForPlayDebugAndroidTestApk - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
+--- com.github.ligi:trulesk:0.19
|    +--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.2
|    |    \--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2
|    |         +--- com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1
|    |         +--- com.android.support.test:rules:0.5
|    |         |    \--- com.android.support.test:runner:0.5
|    |         |         +--- junit:junit:4.12
|    |         |         |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
|    |         |         \--- com.android.support.test:exposed-instrumentation-api-publish:0.5
|    |         +--- com.android.support.test:runner:0.5 (*)
|    |         +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3
|    |         |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
|    |         +--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:2.2.2
|    |         \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3
|    |              \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3 (*)
|    +--- com.jraska:falcon-spoon-compat:1.0.3
|    |    +--- com.jraska:falcon:1.0.3
|    |    \--- com.squareup.spoon:spoon-client:1.6.2
|    \--- com.linkedin.testbutler:test-butler-library:1.1.0
+--- com.squareup.assertj:assertj-android:1.1.1
|    \--- org.assertj:assertj-core:1.7.1
+--- org.mockito:mockito-core:2.7.22
|    +--- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.6.11
|    +--- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:1.6.11
|    \--- org.objenesis:objenesis:2.5
\--- com.linkedin.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:2.2.0
     +--- com.linkedin.dexmaker:dexmaker:2.2.0
     |    \--- com.jakewharton.android.repackaged:dalvik-dx:7.1.0_r7
     |         \--- com.jakewharton.android.repackaged:libcore-dex:7.1.0_r7
     \--- org.mockito:mockito-core:2.2.29 -> 2.7.22 (*)
```

the AppComponent is a dagger component:

```
package org.ligi.passandroid

import dagger.Component
import org.ligi.passandroid.model.PassStore
import org.ligi.passandroid.model.Settings
import org.ligi.passandroid.ui.*
import org.ligi.passandroid.ui.edit.FieldsEditFragment
import org.ligi.passandroid.ui.quirk_fix.USAirwaysLoadActivity
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(AppModule::class, TrackerModule::class))
interface AppComponent {

    fun inject(passViewActivityBase: PassViewActivityBase)

    fun inject(passListActivity: PassListActivity)

    fun inject(passEditActivity: PassEditActivity)

    fun inject(passAdapter: PassAdapter)

    fun inject(passImportActivity: PassImportActivity)

    fun inject(passMenuOptions: PassMenuOptions)

    fun inject(searchPassesIntentService: SearchPassesIntentService)

    fun inject(usAirwaysLoadActivity: USAirwaysLoadActivity)

    fun inject(passAndroidActivity: PassAndroidActivity)

    fun inject(passListFragment: PassListFragment)

    fun inject(passNavigationView: PassNavigationView)

    fun inject(touchImageActivity: TouchImageActivity)

    fun inject(fieldsEditFragment: FieldsEditFragment)

    fun passStore(): PassStore

    fun tracker(): Tracker

    fun settings(): Settings

}
```

there is some strange output in logcat like this:

```
D/dalvikvm( 4357): DexOpt: 'Lcom/android/dex/Annotation;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
D/dalvikvm( 4357): DexOpt: 'Lcom/android/dex/ClassData$Field;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
D/dalvikvm( 4357): DexOpt: 'Lcom/android/dex/ClassData$Method;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
D/dalvikvm( 4357): DexOpt: 'Lcom/android/dex/ClassData;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
D/dalvikvm( 4357): DexOpt: 'Lcom/android/dex/ClassDef;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
D/dalvikvm( 4357): DexOpt: 'Lcom/android/dex/Code$CatchHandler;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
D/dalvikvm( 4357): DexOpt: 'Lcom/android/dex/Code$Try;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
D/dalvikvm( 4357): DexOpt: 'Lcom/android/dex/Code;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
D/dalvikvm( 4357): DexOpt: 'Lcom/android/dex/Dex$1;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
D/dalvikvm( 4357): DexOpt: 'Lcom/android/dex/Dex$ClassDefIterable;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
D/dalvikvm( 4357): DexOpt: 'Lcom/android/dex/Dex$ClassDefIterator;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
D/dalvikvm( 4357): DexOpt: 'Lcom/android/dex/Dex$FieldIdTable;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
D/dalvikvm( 4357): DexOpt: 'Lcom/android/dex/Dex$MethodIdTable;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
D/dalvikvm( 4357): DexOpt: 'Lcom/android/dex/Dex$ProtoIdTable;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
D/dalvikvm( 4357): DexOpt: 'Lcom/android/dex/Dex$StringTable;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
D/dalvikvm( 4357): DexOpt: 'Lcom/android/dex/Dex$TypeIndexToDescriptorIndexTable;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
D/dalvikvm( 4357): DexOpt: 'Lcom/android/dex/Dex$TypeIndexToDescriptorTable;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
D/dalvikvm( 4357): DexOpt: 'Lcom/android/dex/Dex;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
D/dalvikvm( 4357): DexOpt: 'Lcom/android/dex/DexFormat;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
D/dalvikvm( 4357): DexOpt: 'Lcom/android/dex/EncodedValue;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
D/dalvikvm( 4357): DexOpt: 'Lcom/android/dex/EncodedValueCodec;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
D/dalvikvm( 4357): DexOpt: 'Lcom/android/dex/EncodedValueReader;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
D/dalvikvm( 4357): DexOpt: 'Lcom/android/dex/FieldId;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
D/dalvikvm( 4357): DexOpt: 'Lcom/android/dex/Leb128;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
D/dalvikvm( 4357): DexOpt: 'Lcom/android/dex/MethodId;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
D/dalvikvm( 4357): DexOpt: 'Lcom/android/dex/Mutf8;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
D/dalvikvm( 4357): DexOpt: 'Lcom/android/dex/ProtoId;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
D/dalvikvm( 4357): DexOpt: 'Lcom/android/dex/SizeOf;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
D/dalvikvm( 4357): DexOpt: 'Lcom/android/dex/TableOfContents$Section;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
D/dalvikvm( 4357): DexOpt: 'Lcom/android/dex/TableOfContents;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
D/dalvikvm( 4357): DexOpt: 'Lcom/android/dex/TypeList;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
D/dalvikvm( 4357): DexOpt: 'Lcom/android/dex/util/ByteInput;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
D/dalvikvm( 4357): DexOpt: 'Lcom/android/dex/util/ByteOutput;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
D/dalvikvm( 4357): DexOpt: 'Lcom/android/dex/util/ExceptionWithContext;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
D/dalvikvm( 4357): DexOpt: 'Lcom/android/dex/util/FileUtils;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
D/dalvikvm( 4357): DexOpt: 'Lcom/android/dex/util/Unsigned;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
```

I am stuck with this for 2 days and now just ignore the device. No clue on how to proceed from here. The other devices run fine and the app works on the device when manual testing.

EDIT - as requested App and TestApp:

```
package org.ligi.passandroid;

import android.app.Application;
import android.support.annotation.VisibleForTesting;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate;
import com.jakewharton.threetenabp.AndroidThreeTen;
import com.squareup.leakcanary.LeakCanary;
import org.ligi.tracedroid.TraceDroid;
import org.ligi.tracedroid.logging.Log;

public class App extends Application {

    private static AppComponent component;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        component = createComponent();

        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
        installLeakCanary();
        AndroidThreeTen.init(this);
        initTraceDroid();

        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(component.settings().getNightMode());
    }

    public void installLeakCanary() {
        LeakCanary.install(this);
    }

    public AppComponent createComponent() {
        return DaggerAppComponent.builder().appModule(new AppModule(this)).trackerModule(new TrackerModule(this)).build();
    }

    private void initTraceDroid() {
        TraceDroid.init(this);
        Log.setTAG("PassAndroid");
    }

    public static AppComponent component() {
        return component;
    }

    @VisibleForTesting
    public static void setComponent(AppComponent newComponent) {
        component = newComponent;
    }
}
```

and TestApp:

```
public class TestApp extends App {

    @Override
    public AppComponent createComponent() {
        return DaggerTestComponent.builder().testModule(new TestModule()).build();
    }

    public static TestComponent component() {
        return (TestComponent) App.component();
    }

    @Override
    public void installLeakCanary() {

    }

    public static PassStore getPassStore() {
        return component().passStore();
    }

    public static void reset() {
        setComponent(DaggerTestComponent.builder().testModule(new TestModule()).build());
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using multi-dex?

Comment: Try with `@Component(modules = arrayOf(AppModule::class.java, TrackerModule::class.java))`

In Kotlin when you use `Person::class` you get a reference to the Kotlin class (type KClass, see https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/index.html), but if you need a reference to the Java class you must use `Person::class.java`

Comment: @quiro that sounded reasonable but doesn't compile with this error: required:
Array<KClass<*>>
found:
Array<Class<out Any>>

Comment: @JeffersonTavares no

Comment: could you also post the Application class you're using?

Comment: @quiro sure - done & the whole thing is in branch ligi_wip at https://github.com/ligi/PassAndroid